# JavaScript for loop only finds child div class on the first click event

Tags: javascript

I made a very simple application to improve my JavaScript skills instead of using jQuery all the time. What this simple application is supposed to do, is when you click on the `container` div, it will show the `content` div by adding the class `show`. It will remove the class `show` once you click on the `div` `container` again. I might be missing some very basic JavaScript knowledge I'm overlooking here.

**The problem**

This click event on the `container` `div` runs every time. The for loop runs fine every time as well, but after the first click event it seems like it's unable to find the `content` class. This might be because it adds the `show` class in the first click event, but to my knowledge, this is supposed to work fine. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```js
var container = document.querySelector(".container");

container.addEventListener("click", function() {

  // Loop to check child nodes
  for (let i = 0; i < container.childNodes.length; i++) {

    // Check of current child node has classname of content
    if (container.childNodes[i].className == "content") {

      let content = container.childNodes[i];

      console.log("Ran here only once");

      // Check if class already exists
      if (content.classList.contains("show")) {
        content.classList.remove("show");
      } else {
        content.classList.add("show");
      }

      break;
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.container {
  background: red;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.container .title {
  background: blue;
}

.content {
  transition: 1s ease-in-out;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: green;
}

.show {
  max-height: 100%;
  overflow: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="title">
    Some random title text.
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    Some random content text.
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are trying to do ?

```js
var container = document.querySelector(".container");

container.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  [...container.querySelectorAll(".content")].forEach(ele => ele.classList.toggle("show"));
});
```

```css
.container {
  background: red;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.container .title {
  background: blue;
}

.content {
  transition: 1s ease-in-out;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: green;
}

.show {
  max-height: 100%;
  overflow: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="title">
    Some random title text.
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    Some random content text.
  </div>
</div>
```

Or perhaps this:

```js
var container = document.querySelector(".container");

container.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (tgt.classList.contains("title")) {
    tgt.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("show");
  }
});
```

```css
.container {
  background: red;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.container .title {
  background: blue;
}

.content {
  transition: 1s ease-in-out;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: green;
}

.show {
  max-height: 100%;
  overflow: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="title">
    Some random title text.
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    Some random content text.
  </div>
</div>
```